Typing animation changes the position everytime text length changes
My typing animation changes position everytime the text length , how can i make it stay at one place and just do animation
When ever the text to be typed by animtion get smaller it moves to center right and to left when text is in more.
video https://streamable.com/62jzwg
css


.hometxt {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1.4rem;
    height: 50vh;
}
div.hometxt span{
    position: relative;
}
.hometxt span::before{
    content: "FrontEnd Developer";
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    animation: text 20s infinite;
}
.hometxt span::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3rem;
    width: calc(100% + 0.8rem);
    background-color:white;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    animation: cursor 0.8s infinite, typing 20s steps(14) infinite;
    right: -0.5rem;
}
@keyframes cursor {
    To{
        border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    }
}
@keyframes text {
    0%,20%{
        content: "FrontEnd Developer";
    }
    21%,40%{
        content: "PHP Developer";
    }
    41%,60%{
        content: "React/Next Developer";
    }
    61%,80%{
        content: "Web Designer";
    }
    81%,100%{
        content: "Freelancer";
    }
}
@keyframes typing {
    10%,15%,30%,35%,50%,55%,70%,75%,90%,95%{
        width: 0;
    }
    5%,20%,25%,40%,45%,60%,65%,80%,85%{
        width: calc(100% + 0.8rem);
    }
}
 <div class="hometxt">
  <h1>Hi, I am</h1>
  <p>Reyyan Yaqub</p>
  <span></span>
</div>



I tried adding min eidth but didnt work

The problem is that the span is centered within the flexbox container, but the length of the span changes according to what the currently typed "phrase" is. You could give the span itself an appropriate width (if you move the font settings from the before element to the span itself, then a width of about 9.25em should do, for the currently(!) applied phrases) - but then the "cursor" will animate beyond the length of the shorter words. [...]

[...] That again could be avoided, if you wrap the span into an additional element, and give that the width instead. Then everything will be "left-aligned", so that when the longest phrase is shown, that one will look "centered". But the shorter ones will still look kinda "off" then.

Nice challenge. The problem is with .hometxt flex and align-items:center, so child position is adjusted. If you can change it to display : block and give it a left margin you solve your problem

Because the span is centered so it doesn't have constant width that's why cursor appears at different location.
Solution would be wrap the .hometxt in a container and apply certain width then every thing will be left aligned


.main{
  width: max(300px,25vw);
  margin-inline: auto;
}

.hometxt {
    height: 50vh;
}
div.hometxt span{
    position: relative;
}
.hometxt span::before{
    content: "FrontEnd Developer";
    font-size: 2.25rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    animation: text 20s infinite;
}
.hometxt span::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 3rem;
    width: calc(100% + 0.8rem);
    background-color:white;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    animation: cursor 0.8s infinite, typing 20s steps(14) infinite;
    right: -0.5rem;
}
@keyframes cursor {
    To{
        border-left: 2px solid transparent;
    }
}
@keyframes text {
    0%,20%{
        content: "FrontEnd Developer";
    }
    21%,40%{
        content: "PHP Developer";
    }
    41%,60%{
        content: "React/Next Developer";
    }
    61%,80%{
        content: "Web Designer";
    }
    81%,100%{
        content: "Freelancer";
    }
}
@keyframes typing {
    10%,15%,30%,35%,50%,55%,70%,75%,90%,95%{
        width: 0;
    }
    5%,20%,25%,40%,45%,60%,65%,80%,85%{
        width: calc(100% + 0.8rem);
    }
}
<main class='main'>
  <div class="hometxt">
    <h1>Hi, I am</h1>
    <p>Reyyan Yaqub</p>
    <div>
       <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>




THX, its working , now i'll just add margin to it to center it like before

Do you want to something like this:


body {
  background-color:#ce3635;
  text-align: center;
  color:#fff;
  padding-top:10em;
}

* { color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hi, I am</h1>
        <p>Reyyan Yaqub</p>
      <h1>        
        <a href="" class="typewrite" data-period="2000" data-type='[ "FrontEnd Developer", "PHP Developer", "React/Next Developer", "Web Designer", "Freelancer" ]'>
          <span class="wrap"></span>
        </a>
      </h1>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var TxtType = function(el, toRotate, period) {
        this.toRotate = toRotate;
        this.el = el;
        this.loopNum = 0;
        this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
        this.txt = '';
        this.tick();
        this.isDeleting = false;
    };

    TxtType.prototype.tick = function() {
        var i = this.loopNum % this.toRotate.length;
        var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

        if (this.isDeleting) {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length - 1);
        } else {
        this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
        }

        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">'+this.txt+'</span>';

        var that = this;
        var delta = 200 - Math.random() * 100;

        if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

        if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        delta = this.period;
        this.isDeleting = true;
        } else if (this.isDeleting && this.txt === '') {
        this.isDeleting = false;
        this.loopNum++;
        delta = 500;
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
        that.tick();
        }, delta);
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('typewrite');
        for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
            var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-type');
            var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
            if (toRotate) {
              new TxtType(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period);
            }
        }
        // INJECT CSS
        var css = document.createElement("style");
        css.type = "text/css";
        css.innerHTML = ".typewrite > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #fff}";
        document.body.appendChild(css);
    };
      </script>
  </body> 
</html>




yes , This is what im aiming for , but cant this be done in css.
